# Getting error Element type is invalid while learning React Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React. And I am learning React Routing. I created a simple App. Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React Routing</title>
        <script src="/Ch13-01-DisplayInitialFrame/resources/js/react.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Ch13-01-DisplayInitialFrame/resources/js/react-dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/Ch13-01-DisplayInitialFrame/resources/js/babel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/Ch13-01-DisplayInitialFrame/resources/js/react-router-4.0.0-2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/Ch13-01-DisplayInitialFrame/resources/css/reactRouting.css" rel="stylesheet"><script>;
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="/Ch13-01-DisplayInitialFrame/resources/js/reactRouting.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my reactRouting.js

```
var destination = document.querySelector("#container");
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
                <ul className="header">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Stuff</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
                <div className="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <App/>
    </div>,
    destination
);
```

This code works fine. But when I changed my Render to use ReactRouter I am start getting errors

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactRouter.Router>
        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App} />
    </ReactRouter.Router>,
    destination
);
```

The errors are

```
You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your     scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
babel.js (60774,4)
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
react.js (20483,9)
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
react.js (20483,9)
SCRIPT5022: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
react.js (20157,5)
```

What I am doing wrong ? I am using `React v15.3.1`. Do I need any more js to run this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using ReactRouter 4 that has a completely different api then previous version please use [new documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).
I also recommend using a bundler specially when you're getting started with React. [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is a good boilerplate generator for example that takes care of bundler configuration, babel, etc.
Finally in ReactRouter v4 you should use `ReactRouter.BrowserRouter` component based on doc.
If you insist to try react by script tags add ReactRouter using the script link provided in their npm page. I strongly recommend not to use this configuration in a production application.